# top portion gets clipped of in Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

the website is http://sulopa.co.in/kalpproject/en/

when I go to the navbar and click on a menu, it goes to that particular section, but the top portion gets clipped out. It only happens in Firefox browser.

this site doesn't allow me to post images. so chck out the website and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically target Firefox users and then manually add a positive margin and negative padding, to offset the anchor. You'll have to add this class to all anchors (i.e. elements with #frank, etc).

```
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .myAnchor{
         padding-top: 30px; 
         margin-top: -30px;
    }
}
</style>
```